# Why don't my domain's messages to a google group get their headers rewritten so DMARC can pass?

Tags: email, spf, gmail, smtp-headers, dmarc

Whenever my domain sends a message to a google group on another domain the DMARC alignment fails. This is true for all my approved senders, even using Gmail in my domain. It seems to be because the Return-Path (Envelope From) header is replaced by the receiving group's bounce address, but the From header remains as my domain, which is incorrect.

For example, I send mail from Gmail in my domain, chris@mydomain.com, to a group in your domain, your-group@yourdomain.com. If you look at the headers of the message you receive, you see:

**BAD**

```
Return-Path: <your-group+bncBCA5XFGRYQLCBEHHVS5AKGQED3J2I7I@yourdomain.com>
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   dkim=pass header.i=@yourdomain.com;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of your-group+bncBCA5XFGRYQLCBEHHVS5AKGQED3J2I7I@yourdomain.com designates 2607:f8b0:400d:c04::246 as permitted sender)
smtp.mailfrom=your-group+bncBCA5XFGRYQLCBEHHVS5AKGQED3J2I7I@yourdomain.com;
   dmarc=fail (p=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=mydomain.com
From: Chris <chris@mydomain.com>

X-Original-Sender: chris@mydomain.com
X-Original-Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;       dkim=pass
 header.i=@mydomain.com;       spf=pass (google.com: domain of chris@mydomain.com
 designates 2607:f8b0:400c:c05::233 as permitted sender)
smtp.mailfrom=chris@mydomain.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=mydomain.com
```

DMARC fails because of bad alignment between the From domain (mydomain) and the DKIM and SPF domains (yourdomain). However, when you, a properly configured GApps user, send mail from Gmail to a group at mydomain, the headers are different.

**GOOD**

```
Return-Path: <my-group+bncBCGJ3NF22YBRBTXIVS1RKGQEIWR5E6Q@mydomain.com>
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of my-group+bncBCGJ3NF22YBRBTXIVS1RKGQEIWR5E6Q@mydomain.com designates 2607:f8b0:4001:c0b::247 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=my-group+bncBCGJ3NF22YBRBTXIVS1RKGQEIWR5E6Q@mydomain.com;
   dmarc=pass (p=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=mydomain.com
From: "'You' via my-group" <my-group@ mydomain.com>
```

Note the different form of the From header - the original sender has been replaced by my own group. There is also a pair of X-Original headers as above that have the same form (just reversed), so I'm not pasting them.

So the question is, how do I configure my domain, gapps, dns, mx, or whatever, so that Google Groups that receive my messages will correctly replace the From header with "via you-group@yourdomain.com ?"

Mail from my domain to users at other domains work fine - DMARC passes because SPF and DKIM are good and the Return-Path still says @mydomain. I have read articles about why the "via you-group" is necessary - I'm ok with that. I'm trying to figure why my messages to groups are **not** getting treated that way.

Seems to be similar to: [How to prevent emails from my domain through mailing lists to be rejected due to DMARC](https://serverfault.com/questions/598990/how-to-prevent-emails-from-my-domain-through-mailing-lists-to-be-rejected-due-to)
Different because google groups are definitely compatible with DMARC - other people don't have this problem.

**Update:**
I found this article which says google groups only rewrites the sender when the DMARC policy is strict (p=reject). That seems like a terrible idea since the whole point of starting with p=none is to gain confidence that your mail will get delivered when you up the policy, but if true then it may explain my issue. Can anyone confirm?
http://www.spamresource.com/2014/04/google-groups-rewriting-from-addresses.html

Comment: Yes, it's broken by designed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent emails from my domain through mailing lists to be rejected due to DMARC](http://serverfault.com/questions/598990/how-to-prevent-emails-from-my-domain-through-mailing-lists-to-be-rejected-due-to)

Comment: Yeah, Unless you can get either your SPF or DKIM [Identifier Alignments](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/identifieralignments/) Aligned, DMARC is going to fail. There is a new spec to address this issue in the works, you can read more about that here: [ARC Spec](http://arc-spec.org/)

Comment: Possible I explained poorly, but this is a problem that other people have definitely solved. My GOOD example above is a real example - sending from a properly configured GApps domain to a mailing list in my domain works perfectly for them. It's only my outgoing that breaks. This is similar, but not a duplicate, to the post linked by @JennyD; Google groups are not incompatible with DMARC.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I did finally get this response from Google. I was glad to find someone who understood the issue, but unfortunately it looks like Google is sticking with their incorrect treatment of the DMARC directive.

> Google Groups will only rewrite the From: header when the DMARC policy of the original sender (you in this case) is set to reject or quarantine.
>
> With DMARC/p=none, DKIM isn't rewritten when sending to a group, but because DMARC is set to "none", it doesn't matter that the group will break DKIM from the point of view of delivery and spam detection - it will still get delivered properly. Unfortunately, it does make it look confusing if you're monitoring your deployment.
>
> In order to see the correct behavior you can switch to p=quarantine and monitor the delivery. Please tell me if there is anything else I can assist you with, I'll be glad to follow up.

Comment: Link to discussion on GSuite Help Forum: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/GCyP2whcsrM

Comment: See also the "I see 'via' and a website name ..." item, indicating google-groups rewrites only if p=quarantine or p=reject.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1311182?hl=en